# Drag an UI element. Windows Universal Platform

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xaml, win-universal-app

I have been struggling for a few days to find a way to make a UI element drag able in Windows Universal Platform. I'm building a piece of photo editing software that needs to be able to crop images. I have the crop box on screen, but can't figure out how to make so that the user can drag the box to the location they want to crop.[screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OjXIP.png)

The user needs to be able to click on the box circled in red and drag it to any ware on the screen.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use Manipulation[Started/Delta/Completed] events. Try this code:

```
<Grid Background="White">
    <Border Width="150" Height="100" Background="Transparent" BorderBrush="Red" BorderThickness="1"
            ManipulationMode="TranslateX,TranslateY" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" ManipulationDelta="Border_ManipulationDelta">

        <Border.RenderTransform>
            <CompositeTransform x:Name="BorderTransform" />
        </Border.RenderTransform>
    </Border>
</Grid>
```

```
private void Border_ManipulationDelta(object sender, ManipulationDeltaRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    BorderTransform.TranslateX += e.Delta.Translation.X;
    BorderTransform.TranslateY += e.Delta.Translation.Y;
}
```